# env variable CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN with simple vs double dollar sign

Tags: php, git, .env

In the .env file I have to set the variable CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN at `^https?://(.*)(:[0-9]+)?$$`, with the double dollars sign. Every other dev in the team seems to be fine with the single $ at the end.

I can not figure the difference.

I am under Ubuntu, the project is based on API-Platform (symfony)

My solution for now, is to "git stash" before changing branch, and `git stash apply` after.

Answer (score 0):

The double dollar sign `$$` is incorrectly treathed as escape char.

Try to use this instead:
`^https?://(.*)(:[0-9]+)?\$`